# How to handle exceptional page when allocating contiguous cache pages in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, cache, virtual-memory, memory-management

I have a kernel module code which allocates contiguous cache pages. I use  radix_tree_for_each_contig(). Here is the partial snippet of the code.

```
radix_tree_for_each_contig(slot, tree_root, iter, index) {
struct page *page;
page = radix_tree_deref_slot(slot);
if (unlikely(!page)) 
     continue;
if (radix_tree_exceptional_entry(page))
```

In this above code I check for exceptional_entry after radix_tree_deref_slot(). In latest kernel (4.x) radix_tree_exceptional_entry() returns non-zero where as same code in older kernel 3.13.x gives zero.

So my question is how do I handle exceptional_entry while allocating contiguous pages in cache ?